# How to get ThemeContext state as variable in Javascript inside react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm using Gatsby to make a simple ReactJS app that uses **useContext** hook and **ThemeContext** to add an option of dark theme to the app.
Now, I have another component that uses react-helmet to add external JS files to the page.
There is some code in these files that I want to connect to the theme state.

I am able to access the theme state on the 'index.js' page as :

```
const { dark } = useContext(ThemeContext)
```

I want to write some code in the external file 'myscript.js' like

```
let isDark = dark
if(isDark){
   console.log("Dark theme")
}
else{
   console.log("Light theme")
}
```

where 'dark' is from the theme.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a global data property on the window object that you can use anywhere in your project. You can name this anything on the window. In this case I've use `__globalData__` to prevent [name collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_collision).

```
window.__globalData__ = {
  theme: 'light'
}
```

From within the Provider component of the context use `useEffect` to listen for changes in the theme and update the global value if necessary.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import ThemeContext from './ThemeContext' // Assuming this is the path

const ThemeProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [ theme, setTheme ] = useState('light')
  
  useEffect(() => {
    window.__globalData__ = window.__globalData__ || {} // Make sure global data is defined.
    window.__globalData__.theme = theme
  }, [theme])

  return(
    <ThemeContext.Provider values={[ theme, setTheme ]}>
      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default ThemeProvider
```

Then use a function to check the value of the global property.

```
/**
 * Check if dark theme is set when globalData is set on window object.
 * Or return false when globalData is not set, meaning theme is light.
 */
const isDark = () => 
  window.__globalData__ && window.__globalData__.theme ? 
    window.__globalData__.theme === 'dark' :
    false

if (isDark()) {
  console.log("Dark theme")
}
else{
  console.log("Light theme")
}
```

Alternatively you could use events to do something whenever the theme changes.

To stay in the world of hooks, you could create your own hook that dispatches a [`CustomEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent) with the current theme as `detail` property.

```
const useThemeEvents = () => {
  const dispatch = theme => {
    const event = new CustomEvent('themechange', {
      detail: { theme }
    })
    window.dispatchEvent(event)
  }
  return { dispatch }
}

export { useThemeEvents }
```

And then use the hook in your provider component.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import ThemeContext from './ThemeContext' // Assuming this is the path
import { useThemeEvents } from './hooks' // Also assuming this is the path

const ThemeProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [ theme, setTheme ] = useState('light')
  const { dispatch } = useThemeEvents()
  
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(theme)
  }, [theme])

  return(
    <ThemeContext.Provider values={[ theme, setTheme ]}>
      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default ThemeProvider
```

Now in your added JS file listen for the `themechange` event on the window object.

```
window.addEventListener('themechange', ({ detail }) => {
  const { theme } = detail
  if (theme === 'dark') {
    console.log("Dark theme")
  } else {
    console.log("Light theme")
  }
})
```